# Apply function with multiple parameters to column dataframe

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe, apply

I have this Dataframe

```
data=pandas.Dataframe({'a':[1,2,3]})
```

and this function:

```
def mi(x,y):
    return x*y
```

I want a column 'b' as a result of apply function 'mi' where x and y are random numbers.

Comment: So what is the role of `data` in your question?

Comment: There are multiple ways of generating random numbers... `x` and `y` are supposed to be integers or floats? And what's the range of possible values?

Comment: I put the variables x and y as an example of two parameters. The real function is bigger and depends on three external variables of the DataFrame. X and Y depend on the specific condition of each column (data, distributions, conditions to apply it, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried `data['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x,y: mi(x,y))` ?